# What container interface(s) does Docker port mapping (`-p <host-port>:<container-port>`) apply to?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

> Which container interface does Docker port mapping (`-p <host-port>:<container-port>`) apply to?

After having read the Docker documentation, I'm not sure what network interface(s) in the Docker container a Docker port mapping like (1) and (2) applies to.

By default a new container is created with two interfaces `eth0` and `lo`, but more can be added.

(1) is shorthand for `-p 0.0.0.0:8080:80`.

(2) refers to the network interface on the host with IP address `192.168.1.100`, and it maps host port `8080` to container port `80`, but on what container interface?

```
(1) -p 8080:80  Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.

(2) -p 192.168.1.100:8080:80    Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host for connections to host IP 192.168.1.100.
```

Do (1) and (2) map host port `8080` to container port `80` on ALL container interfaces (`0.0.0.0`)? If, so where can I see that in the documentation, and can this behaviour be restricted to a specific set of container interfaces?

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: It's unusual to think about "container interfaces" at this level of detail; usually the only important thing is that inbound connections will arrive on a container's `eth0` and so if the container process bind(2) to 127.0.0.1 then it won't actually get inbound connections.  Are you trying to do something like map specific host interfaces to multiple listeners inside a container?  Doing this at the port level will work a little better.

Comment: What do you mean by "map specific host interfaces to multiple listeners inside a container?".
My problem is that a process inside the container binds to `127.0.0.1:8080`, but if I specify `-p 8080:8080`, then the process don't get the connection (why?) when connecting to my host's `127.0.0.1:8080`. Testing this with netcat, it reports `127.0.0.1:8080` as open, but the container process don't get the connection, which it does, if it binds to `eth0` instead.

Comment: @DavidMaze - do you have a reference documenting: "usually the only important thing is that inbound connections will arrive on a container's eth0"?

Answer (score 2):

TCP connections have a single starting point (IP+port) and single end point (IP+port). As such, the port forwarding can only map to *one* IP address in the container. Specifically, the bridge network interface.

"Can this behavior be restricted to a specific set of container interfaces" doesn't really make sense, then: by the nature of TCP, there's only ever one interface that's being connected to.

If you're worried that things listening on 127.0.0.1 inside the container will be come public, then don't; they won't (and can't).

https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/ has a bunch of diagrams that might make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks, by bridge network interface, you mean the `eth0` interface created automatically? In my case, I have a container process that binds to `127.0.0.1:8080`. How can I access this from the host? Do I need to set up `iptables` firewall rules, or can it be configured using `docker`?

Comment: Do you have a resource documenting the statement: "Specifically, the bridge network interface."?

Comment: `you mean the eth0 interface created automatically?` - the container sees eth0. Depending on the docker network driver, host sees different interface. Usually bridge network driver is used, so host sees a bridge interface connected to containers. `How can I access this from the host?` Just like you would have two machines connected with a cable. Connect to `<ip address of container>:8080`. `Do you have a resource documenting` [docker bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).

Comment: @KamilCuk - so, you are saying I can connect to a container process listening on `127.0.0.1:80801 by connecting to the containers IP address? Are you sure?

Answer (score -1):

> Do (1) and (2) map host port 8080 to container port 80 on ALL container interfaces (0.0.0.0)

Not exactly. (1) maps host port 8080 to container port 80 on all **host** interfaces. (2) maps host port 8080 on **host** interface with ip address 192.168.1.100 to containers port 80.

Specifically, it does something along (copying from my machine):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrypte --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
iptables -t nat -A DOCKER ! -i <bridge docker interface> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination <container-IP-address>
```

In net:PREROUTING the traffic for dport 8080 is redirected to container IP Address.

I believe you seem to be confused and assume that containers have multiple interfaces. Container has (usually) one interface and is connected to one docker network.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer needs to be more general. A container may have more interfaces, and by default it has two interfaces: `lo` and `eth0`. My question asks what container interface the port mapping (`-p`) targets.

Comment: Meh, I didn't count `lo` as a "real" interface... So it "targets" eth0 from the container side.